# Hello, I want to get multiple custom field from wordpress with one line

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i want to get multiple custom field from wordpress with one line for example. I have field "link","link1","link2","link3","link4" and "link_titull","link_titull1","link_titull2","link_titull3","link_titull4"

I have the code to get just one field and if its not filled its showing empty.

```
<?php $prop_det_url = get_field('link');
     if($prop_det_url!=''){ ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank">&gt; <?php the_field('link_titull'); ?></a></p>
     <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop. See sample code below:

```
<?php 
for( $i=1; $i<=4; $i++){

    $prop_det_url = get_field('link'.$i);

    if( $prop_det_url != '' ){ ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank">&gt; <?php the_field('link_titul'.$i); ?></a>

    <?php } 
}
?>
```